# preg_split não está quebrando as strings no array

Tags: php, array, string, regex

Não estou conseguindo utilizar a função `preg_split()` corretamente.

Estou tentando quebrar uma String num `array()` via *regex* mas não está rolando.

```
$string = "<:termo.9:><:termo.10:><:termo.11:>";
$res = preg_split("/(<:)(nome|termo)(.)(\d+)(:>)/", $string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

O valor atribuído a `$res` é:

```
        Array ( 
          [0] => 
          [1] => <: 
          [2] => termo 
          [3] => . 
          [4] => 9 
          [5] => :> 
          [6] => 
          [7] => <: 
          [8] => termo 
          [9] => . 
          [10] => 12 
          [11] => :> 
          [12] => 
          [13] => <: 
          [14] => termo 
          [15] => . 
          [16] => 10 
          [17] => :> 
          [18] => 
          [19] => <: 
          [20] => termo 
          [21] => . 
          [22] => 11 
          [23] => :> 
        )
```

E na verdade gostaria de:

```
Array (
           [0] => "<:termo.9:>"
           [1] => "<:termo.10:>"
           [2] => "<:termo.11:>"
       )
```

Uma solução paliativa seria utilizar a seguinte *pattern*:

```
$res = preg_split("/(<:nome\.\d+:>|<:termo\.\d+:>)/", $string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

E o `$res` sai:

```
Array ( 
          [0] => 
          [1] => <:termo.9:> 
          [2] => 
          [3] => <:termo.12:> 
          [4] => 
          [5] => <:termo.10:> 
          [6] => 
          [7] => <:termo.11:> 
          [8] => 
          [9] => <:termo.9:> 
          [10] => 
        )
```

Mas se observar bem, as condições impostas são:

```
(<:nome\.\d+:>|<:termo\.\d+:>)
```

E as variações de nomenclaturas que poderei usar pode aumentar, como:

> <:nome.2:>, <:text.4:>,<:codigo.5:>,etc

e desta forma o código não estaria "*otimizado*", digamos assim.

O que pode estar errado na *pattern* para que seja melhorada?

Comment: Já tentou colocando no 4º parâmetro `preg_split_delim_capture`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters realmente retornou o `array` quebrando a String, mas quebrou cada condição do `pattern`. Ex: `Array([0]=>"<:",[1]=>"nome",[2]=>"."...etc)`

Comment: É praticamente impossível fazer isso utilizando o `preg_split`, porque, essa função, procura por referências específicas para dividir o código. É praticamente uma versão melhorada do `explode`, se posso assim dizer.

Comment: @Edilson acho que compreendi melhor agora. Talvez a solução que necessito não seja exatamente utilizar `preg_split` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$foo = "<:termo.9:><:termo.10:><:termo.11:><:nome.2:><:text.4:><:codigo.5:>";

preg_match_all("/<:[a-z]+\.[0-9]+:>/s", $foo, $bar);

print_r($bar);
```

Retornará:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <:termo.9:>
            [1] => <:termo.10:>
            [2] => <:termo.11:>
            [3] => <:nome.2:>
            [4] => <:text.4:>
            [5] => <:codigo.5:>
        )

)
```

Comment: Acho que é isso.. rsrs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

O problema não é bem o `pattern`, a função `preg_split`, procura pelo padrão para quebrar a string em partes, ou seja é similar ao `explode`, contudo, nela você pode definir um padrão de explosão que não se limita a mesma sequencia sempre.

#### Exemplo

```
$string = "teste_de_explosão-de-string";
$res = preg_split('/_|-/', $string); // vai explodir por '_' e por '-'
```

No seu caso seria uma captura e não uma explosão, e para isso pode ser usado o `preg_match_all`.

#### No seu caso

```
$string = "<:termo.9:><:termo.10:><:termo.11:>";
preg_match_all("/(<:(nome|termo)\.\d+:>)/", $string, $res);
```

Para recuperar os valores previamente agrupados, utilize:

```
foreach($res[1] as $id=>$val){
    $arr[] = $val;  
}

print_r($arr);
```

#### Obs

Para capturar `.` literal em `REGEX` deve se escapar o mesmo `\.`, pois ele representa qualquer coisa.

Comment: Ajudou em Partes o que necessito, pois realmente precisava de um `explode` utilizando uma condição *regex*. Mas a *patter* que instruiu acima melhorou minha situação.

Comment: Ah, o `preg_match_all` faz basicamente isto.

Comment: Faltou testar um pouco mais a função para compreende-la. Acho que é isso! Muito obrigado!